# Given a set of points in 3-d space, how to find its geometry.

Tags: geometry

Here I am having problem in finding the geometry of a given set. Given set is {a,a+b,a+b } where a,b are arbitrary reals. Its given that it represents a plane passing through origin. How it does so. How to proceed in such problems. I have no idea. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Hint: you seem to have $z=y$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually in these type of problems , you have to get some relation or condition including x,y and z using given conditions. 
Here you have given conditions in terms of two variables a and b.
x=a , y=a+b , z=a+b 
Now , you have to somehow eliminate a and b , one way is 
y-x=b=z-x so , y-x=z-x or y=z.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the plane is simply: y=z or y-z=0, as x is completely free.